# How To Create TimerHandler Using Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio, handler

I'm working on a project using C++.

I want a TimerHandler to be called after a specified time, but at the same time I don't want to block the current thread or any code after io.run() in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class TimerTest
{
public:
    static void PrintOutTimerHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, const std::string& message)
    {
        std::cout << "PrintOutTimerHandler called: " << ", message: " << message << std::endl;
    }

    void run()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer dt(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

        std::cout << "Start:\t" << std::endl;

        dt.async_wait(boost::bind(PrintOutTimerHandler, boost::asio::placeholders::error, std::string("here is the message")));

        // Do some job here
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            ++i, --i;

        std::cout << "End:\t" << std::endl;

        io.run();

        std::cout << "When to reach here 1: " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TimerTest tt;
    tt.run();

    std::cout << "When to reach here 2: " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

/* Current output:
Start:
End:
PrintOutTimerHandler called: , message: here is the message
When to reach here 1:
When to reach here 2:
 */

/* Expected output:
Start:
End:
When to reach here 1:
When to reach here 2:
PrintOutTimerHandler called: , message: here is the message
 */
```

I think I made myself clear.  My questions are:

- If this can be solved without
  introducing a new thread, like Flex
  ActionScript, that's is the best, but
  I guess not (I guess ActionScript is
  using a hidden thread);
- If we have to
  introduce an extra thread to do the
  job, would you mind writing down the
  pseudo code for me?

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example . Run the io_service in a separate thread

```
asio::io_service io_service;
asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

or run it in a thread group

```
boost::thread_group threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < my_thread_count; ++i)
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

Remember that your main thread should always run because when it exists all threads spawned will also exit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I'm trying to apply the new thread to my example.  But I don't know how, would you please help me out?

Comment: @OcrunC, pls ignore my comment above.  I got it working. Thanks.

Comment: would you mind having a look at my another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076524/why-my-eventtimer-implemented-by-boostasioio-service-and-boostdeadline-time

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood what OrcunC said, but actually he is correct.  Here is the modified version for your reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class TimerTest
{
public:
    static void PrintOutTimerHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, const std::string& message)
    {
        std::cout << "PrintOutTimerHandler called: " << ", message: " << message << std::endl;
    }

    TimerTest(unsigned int timeout)
        : dt(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout))
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::cout << "Start:\t" << std::endl;

        dt.async_wait(boost::bind(PrintOutTimerHandler, boost::asio::placeholders::error, std::string("here is the message")));

        boost::thread thrd(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));

        // Do some job here
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            ++i, --i;

        std::cout << "End:\t" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "When to reach here 1: " << std::endl;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service     io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer dt;
};

int main()
{
    TimerTest tt(5000);
    tt.run();

    std::cout << "When to reach here 2: " << std::endl;

    // Keep the main thread active for testing purpose. Otherwise,
    // once the TimerTest object is destroyed when exiting the main() function,
    // the sub thread spawed in tt.run() will also exit;
    Sleep(10000);
}

/* Current output and Expected output:
Start:
End:
When to reach here 1:
When to reach here 2:
PrintOutTimerHandler called: , message: here is the message
 */
```

Comment: Just an addition - the CMakeLists.txt required to build the above example is: 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(OneShotTimer)

find_package(Boost 1.40.0 REQUIRED system thread)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OneShotTimer OneShotTimer.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(OneShotTimer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Comment: The handler is never called for me? I had to change Sleep(10000) to usleep(10000) to get it to compile (I'm on Linux), but my output is "Start: 
End: 
When to reach here 1: 
When to reach here 2: " - I never see the "PrintOutTimerHandler called: , message: here is the message" like you show in your output.