# Implementing an event timer using boost::asio

Tags: c++, events, boost, timer, boost-asio

The sample code looks long, but actually it's not so complicated :-)

**What I'm trying to do is, when a user calls EventTimer.Start(), it will execute the callback handler (which is passed into the ctor) every `interval` milliseconds for `repeatCount` times.**

You just need to look at the function EventTimer::Stop()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include <ctime>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string CurrentDateTimeTimestampMilliseconds() {
    double ms = 0.0;            // Milliseconds

    struct timeb curtime;
    ftime(&curtime);
    ms = (double) (curtime.millitm);

    char timestamp[128];

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tp = localtime(&now);
    sprintf(timestamp, "%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d.%03.0f",
            tp->tm_year + 1900, tp->tm_mon + 1, tp->tm_mday, tp->tm_hour, tp->tm_min, tp->tm_sec, ms);

    return std::string(timestamp);
}

class EventTimer
{
public:
    static const int kDefaultInterval     = 1000;
    static const int kMinInterval         = 1;
    static const int kDefaultRepeatCount  = 1;
    static const int kInfiniteRepeatCount = -1;
    static const int kDefaultOffset       = 10;

public:
    typedef boost::function<void()> Handler;

    EventTimer(Handler handler = NULL)
        : interval(kDefaultInterval),
          repeatCount(kDefaultRepeatCount),
          handler(handler),
          timer(io),
          exeCount(-1)
    {

    }

    virtual ~EventTimer()
    {

    }

    void SetInterval(int value)
    {
//        if (value < 1)
//            throw std::exception();

        interval = value;
    }

    void SetRepeatCount(int value)
    {
//        if (value < 1)
//            throw std::exception();

        repeatCount = value;
    }

    bool Running() const
    {
        return exeCount >= 0;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        io.reset(); // I don't know why I have to put io.reset here,
                    // since it's already been called in Stop()
        exeCount = 0;

        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(interval));
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&EventTimer::EventHandler, this));
        io.run();
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        if (Running())
        {
            // How to reset everything when stop is called???
            //io.stop();
            timer.cancel();
            io.reset();

            exeCount = -1; // Reset
        }
    }

private:
    virtual void EventHandler()
    {
        // Execute the requested operation
        //if (handler != NULL)
        //    handler();
        std::cout << CurrentDateTimeTimestampMilliseconds() << ": exeCount = " << exeCount + 1 << std::endl;

        // Check if one more time of handler execution is required
        if (repeatCount == kInfiniteRepeatCount || ++exeCount < repeatCount)
        {
            timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(interval));
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&EventTimer::EventHandler, this));
        }
        else
        {
            Stop();
            std::cout << CurrentDateTimeTimestampMilliseconds() << ": Stopped" << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int                         interval;    // Milliseconds
    int                         repeatCount; // Number of times to trigger the EventHandler
    int                         exeCount;    // Number of executed times
    boost::asio::io_service     io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    Handler                     handler;
};

int main()
{
    EventTimer etimer;

    etimer.SetInterval(1000);
    etimer.SetRepeatCount(1);

    std::cout << CurrentDateTimeTimestampMilliseconds() << ": Started" << std::endl;
    etimer.Start();
    // boost::thread thrd1(boost::bind(&EventTimer::Start, &etimer));

    Sleep(3000); // Keep the main thread active

    etimer.SetInterval(2000);
    etimer.SetRepeatCount(1);

    std::cout << CurrentDateTimeTimestampMilliseconds() << ": Started again" << std::endl;
    etimer.Start();
    // boost::thread thrd2(boost::bind(&EventTimer::Start, &etimer));

    Sleep(5000); // Keep the main thread active
}

/* Current Output:
20110520-125506.781: Started
20110520-125507.781: exeCount = 1
20110520-125507.781: Stopped
20110520-125510.781: Started again
 */

/* Expected Output (timestamp might be slightly different with some offset)
20110520-125506.781: Started
20110520-125507.781: exeCount = 1
20110520-125507.781: Stopped
20110520-125510.781: Started again
20110520-125512.781: exeCount = 1
20110520-125512.781: Stopped
 */
```

I don't know why that my second time of calling to EventTimer::Start() does not work at all.  My questions are:

1. What should I do in
   EventTimer::Stop() in order to reset
   everything so that next time of
   calling Start() will work?
2. Is there anything else I have to modify?
3. If I use another thread to start the EventTimer::Start() (see the commented code in the main function), when does the thread actually exit?

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, but I don't know why that I have to put `io.reset()` in `Start()`, since it's already been called in Stop().

See the updated code in the post.

Comment: The flow of execution for resuming/restarting an io_service is start(), stop(), reset. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html

Comment: @Sean, io_service does not have a method start(). You mean run()? Yes, run(), stop(), reset(), that's what I was trying to do. but it does not work out.

Comment: Only after I put "io.reset()" in my Start() method, it worked.

Comment: ack! yes, `run()` -> `stop()` -> `reset()` -> `run()`.... I don't think you've quite grasped how to integrate ASIO with your application. In your application under normal circumstances (of which I think you fall under), you should never ever need to call `reset()` and you should only call `stop()` when you shut your program down.

Comment: This seems to be a bug/curious behavior. Maybe reset does not trigger resetting when a handler is currently executing. (you are in one, when you call reset). Have to look through the code to confirm this 'hunch'.

Comment: @Sean/Christopher,  thanks for your comments.  I'm new to boost library.  My current implementation might not good for a production-level project.  But I just don't know how to do with such a simple EventTimer (as in other languages).  Please see the bold text in my post for what I'm trying to do.   I understand my current implementation might look buggy, but I just could not google/find a solution.

Comment: (Cont.) I saw a lot of samples, within which asio::io_services is always passed into a ctor by reference (though I don't know why I cannot put it inside the class). If either of you has any code or reference about this or my EventTimer, please let me know.

Comment: Peter, try the example that I posted here and see if this answers your question: https://github.com/sean-/Boost.Examples/tree/master/asio/timer  Lastly, have you tried putting io.stop() below your timer.cancel() call?

Answer (score 2):

As Sam hinted, depending on what you're attempting to accomplish, most of the time it is considered a design error to stop an io_service. You do not need to `stop()`/`reset()` the io_service in order to reschedule a timer.

Normally you would leave a thread or thread pool running attatched to an `io_service` and then you would schedule whatever event you need with the `io_service`. With the `io_service` machinery in place, leave it up to the `io_service` to dispatch your scheduled work as requested and then you only have to work with the events or work requests that you schedule with the `io_service`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but there's a couple of things that are incorrect in the code you have posted.

1. `io_service::reset()` should only be invoked after a previous invocation of `io_service::run()` was stopped or ran out of work as the [documentation describes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html).
2. you should not need explicit calls to `Sleep()`, the call to `io_service::run()` will block as long as it has work to do.

Comment: I am trying to do is something like a event timer, the user can pass an Handler (default is NULL) to the constructor, SetInterval() and SetRepeatCount(), that is, the user can let the EventTimer to do the job (Handler) every Interval milliseconds for RepearCount timers.

Comment: "io_service::reset() should only be invoked after a previous invocation of io_service::run()", I agree with you.  That's why in the original post, there is no "io.reset()", instead, I put "io.reset" in the Stop().  but it was not working as expected.  So later, I put the "io.reset()" in the Start(), now it's working.

Comment: @Peter it is not clear to me what this event timer offers instead of a `deadline_timer`. The control flow of your program is also not clear, as my answer indicates it is quite odd to inject `Sleep()` into an asynchronous design.

Comment: thanks for your kind help.  The "Sleep()" is for demo purpose.  I just want to make sure my main thread is active.  I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear on what I was trying to do.  So I edited my post.  Pls check it out.